# App tries to open an URL with a custom protocol/scheme, browser protests

Tags: applications, google-play-store, lineageos, url, authentication

[This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.hafas.android.db&hl=de&gl=US) tries to handle logins through the browser with a custom "protocol"/scheme in the URI, i.e. instead of `https://...`, it tries to open `dbnavigator://idm_auth/login?...`, but the browser (Google Chrome) says "Web page not available", "net::UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME".

How do I help the app explain to the browser how to access that address?

Comment: What Android version do you use? And is the used ROM stock or custom (with root)? Which button triggers the custom scheme URL, I see for example the login and sync button in my tickets but that leads me to a normal web page.

Comment: @Robert It's a LineageOS 19 (so Android 12?) ROM that was made for this phone (probably with root). I'm using that because the official Android at some point refused to update, and that app refused to install on the old Android version. The login procedure *after* typing in the login details leads to `dbnavigator://idm_auth/login?...`

Answer (score 0):

Before `dbnavigator://idm_auth/login?...`, an URL like `https://...` briefly flashed on the screen, so I managed to quickly tap it and then tap "Copy" or "Cut", then pasted it into Firefox on the phone and proceeded in the browser. After a few steps in Firefox, the app appeared and worked.